# Pandas groupby and sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which consists of three columns A ,B ,C and I need to sum up values based on row values

Below is the scenario

```
A            B               C

Distance_a  distance_b       5
Distance_a  distance_c       6

distance_b  distance_c       7

distance_b  distance_d       7

distance_d  Distance_a       9
```

if I want to find out cumulative distance from distance_A, I need my code to add 5,6 and also it is supposed to consider last column that is distance_d Distance _a and it need to add 9 as well

So cumulative distance from a will be 5+6+9 = 20

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the raw pandas dataframe code first that contains the data.

Comment: What is your expected out put ?

Answer (score 1):

@Hongpei's answer is certainly more efficient, but if you just want the sum of distance_a. You can do the following as well

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = {'A':['distance_a', 'distance_a', 'distance_b', 'distance_b', 'distance_d'],
        'B':['distance_b', 'distance_c', 'distance_c', 'distance_d', 'distance_a'],
        'C':[5, 6, 7, 7, 9]}

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by columns A and B individually
col_A_groupby = df.groupby(['A']).sum()
col_B_groupby = df.groupby(['B']).sum()

# Sum the values together
dist_a_sum = col_A_groupby.loc['distance_a'] + col_B_groupby.loc['distance_a']
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be a easy workaround, suppose your original DataFrame is df, then you only need to:

```py
pd.concat([df[['A','C']],
           df[['B','C']].rename(columns={'B':'A'})],
          sort=False).groupby('A').sum()
```

Basically what I did is to concat df[['A','C']] and df[['B','C']] together (while rename the second df columns to ['A','C']), and then groupby

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, a `melt` and `sum` are enough

```
s = df.melt('C').groupby('value').C.sum()
print(s)

Out[113]:
value
Distance_a    20
distance_b    19
distance_c    13
distance_d    16
Name: C, dtype: int64
```